# Import error while using pyshark

Tags: python, wireshark-dissector, pyshark

I am trying to install pyshark in windows. [Python 2.6].
When I try to import pyshark in my python code.
I get the following error -

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pyshark\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyshark.capture.live_capture import LiveCapture
  File "pyshark\capture\live_capture.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyshark.capture.capture import Capture
  File "pyshark\capture\capture.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyshark.tshark.tshark_xml import packet_from_xml_packet
  File "pyshark\tshark\tshark_xml.py", line 4, in <module>
    import lxml.objectify
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.**
```

looks like the lxml.objectify is not available, but I have installed lxml.

Comment: Can you import `lxml.objectify` directly, or do you get an ImportError?

Comment: I get an import error

Comment: ...so...it appears that you don't have lxml installed (or at least correctly).

Comment: I found from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshark/0.2.5.

Comment: @user2746064: How did you install that package?  If you used something like pip, it should have either 1) installed lxml; 2) issued an error saying that it couldn't.  From your error, you don't have it installed.  You could try this command on the command-line:  pip install lxml (which may or may not work depending on your configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Windows (and it looks like you are), download and install lxml from Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml).

Then you should be able to use pyshark.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I tried different packages for Python. You can try firstly `pip install xyz`, if it is not workable then swift to `Anaconda` or `miniconda` and write `conda install xyz` in `cmd`.